# Play video url from server without streaming

Tags: ios, swift, video, video-streaming

I am working with iOS app(Swift).

If we place video file on server, do we need streaming?

What about if someone just store video file on server and I can get only url of that file without streaming service?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to download the file to the device in order for it to not be "streaming". Either way, streaming or download, you'll have to get the data from the server to your device.

1. **Streaming**: You won't have to store the file locally on the users phone. Which is good because devices tend to be lacking on extra memory. If the user is only going to watch the video once or twice, this is a good option.
2. **Download**: You only have to transfer the data once. However they won't be able to see the video until it's fully downloaded. If it's a video the user will watch multiple times this is a viable option because you won't have to eat up data each time they want to see it.

Comment: Thank you very much for an explanation!

Comment: @Svitlana of course, let me know if you have any other questions.